# iOS-Not able to install enterprise app on few devices

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, diawi

My client distributed our enterprise app. On every device, it is getting installed but there are 2 devices iPhone X and iPhone SE with iOS version 11.4 it is not getting downloaded showing "App cannot be download at this time". They are making a link using Diawi to share among their employees. 
Please, can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

If your client has the project ask them to check the **Deployment Info** section in the Xcode project. If the option selected against Devices is Universal, you should not have any problem installing it on any iOS device (iPhone, or IPad). But if the value for Devices is set to either iPhone or iPad you can install the app only on the selected device type.

> Also Do remember to register the UDIDs of the devices on which the app
>   will be downloaded

.